# I see 11K active Spanner Sessions will it cause memory issue? or timeout issues?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-spanner

I see issue with Liveness Probe and there is timeout. Then PODs are restarting. At the container I see Errors with code 137 (memory issue)

Our backend database is Spanner. It is Springboot application.

gcloud spanner databases sessions list --instance my-instance --database my-db

Gives a count of 11450 active sessions.
Any pointers on this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Error code 137 indicates failure as the container received SIGKILL. This error is normally experienced when the application is experiencing higher than normal load. To remediate you should increase the limit of your container or pod. If there's no spike in load, you should investigate if there are any memory leaks on your application.   
You should check the logs to identify what threshold was breached that caused the SIGKILL. Possible causes are out of memory, disk usage, cpu utilization. Upon knowing what caused the exit 137, you can increase the resource that is lacking.

Comment: thanks, Michael C
I understand the possible reason for the exit code 137. 
I like to know what will be the impact if there is more active spanner session that is created by the Spring-boot application.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions idle for more than 1 hour will be deleted by the server ([source](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions#handle_deleted_sessions)).

Your pod has already restarted and do not know about these obsolete sessions. So there is no impact on the client side.